# How do I satisfy IntelliJ IDEA's expectation that my scala class's companion object's declaration be tested?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

```
case class Point(x: Double = 0,
                 y: Double = 0,
                 z: Double = 0) extends Point3D(x, y, z) {


  def +(that: Point): Point = new Point(x + that.x, y + that.y, z + that.z)
  def -(that: Point): Point = new Point(x - that.x, y - that.y, z - that.z)
  def *(that: Point): Point = new Point(x * that.x, y * that.y, z * that.z)
  def /(that: Point): Point = new Point(x / that.x, y / that.y, z / that.z) 
}

object Point {
  def apply(p3d: Point3D) = new Point(p3d.getX, p3d.getY, p3d.getZ)
}
```

IntelliJ is giving this code 92% coverage because the line `object Point {` is being counted in coverage, but I cannot figure out why or how to satisfy it's expectation. I have tried comparing it to something, tried adding another method and calling that... No such luck, and I am out of ideas.

EDIT: Here is the test code.

```
import javafx.geometry.Point3D

import org.scalatest._

class test_Point extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  val u = Point(100, 200, 300)
  val v = Point(623, -85, 300)

  it should "supply zero-valued defaults" in {
    val p = Point()
    p.x should be (0)
    p.y should be (0)
    p.z should be (0)
  }

  it should "be constructable from base class" in {
    val p = Point(new Point3D(0, 0, 0))
  }

  it should "implement + operator" in {
    val w = Point(u.x+v.x, u.y+v.y, u.z+v.z)
    u + v should be (w)
  }

  it should "implement - operator" in {
    val w = Point(u.x-v.x, u.y-v.y, u.z-v.z)
    u - v should be (w)
  }

  it should "implement * operator" in {
    val w = Point(u.x*v.x, u.y*v.y, u.z*v.z)
    u * v should be (w)
  }

  it should "implement / operator" in {
    val w = Point(u.x/v.x, u.y/v.y, u.z/v.z)
    u / v should be (w)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `Point` is a case class, the companion object will automatically be populated with an apply method taking, in this case, 3 doubles. It may be this method that is not being covered. There is also an unapply method, and the case class itself will have equals, hashcode, toString and copy methods created for it, which you might need to cover.

Comment: Not sure, but could it be that the defaults in the constructor matter, too?

Comment: Sascha: Do you mean for Point itself? That was indeed a small point of confusion, I had to create a test that produced a no-args Point and ensured the axes were all 0.

Comment: Shadowlands: I've gone ahead and added the test code to the original post. As you can see I call the Point(Double, Double, Double) 'case constructor', but I haven't tested those default methods you suggest, so I will try that, although it seems odd that it's not expecting me to test those methods in the actual case class.

Comment: Alas, I have tried calling all those methods in the tests (and a couple you didn't mention, like unapply(Point)). Still nothing! The mystery continues...